# Asus UX430UQ Laptop Microphone not working Ubuntu 18.04 or 20.04

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, asus, microphone

The microphone of my Asus laptop UX430UQ is not working using Ubuntu 18.04 or 20.04. It took me far too long to find out what the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

Create the file /etc/modprobe.d/fix_headset_microphone.conf:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/fix_headset_microphone.conf
```

Add this line to the file:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=alc255-asus
```